# Spring Integration multiple context

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I would like to ask what exactly is happening while importing multiple Spring Integration contexts?

Does the channel nodes overrides each other if they match in subsequent contexts? Or is there some mechanism to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Integration application is just a Spring application, hence it follows with all configuration rules.

When you import several context they all are squished to the single application context.

And it doesn't matter which bean types you override (channel are beans too). If several beans have the same name, the last one will win, by default.

It's not so easy to change that behaviour - `DefaultListableBeanFactory#setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false)`

From other side you can switch on the `INFO` logging level for the `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory` category and you'll see the overriden beans on application start up.

It's recommended to use unique bean names and, actually, IDEs complain, when several beans have the same names.